# how multiple OR's and AND evaluate

Tags: if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

This is very simple question, but I can't get it. I have simple condition:

```
bool c = true || true || true && false;
```

Why this evaluation is `true`? As far as I know it evaluates like this:

`true || true || true && false` => `true || true && false` => `true && false` => `false`

But guess im wrong.

Comment: `true || true && false` => `true` since it's `true or something else` why would we need to check something else if we know if first condition is true... Read left to right or use brackets to break up the operations.

Comment: The precedence of OR and AND can vary with language. You need to specify that.  E.g. in bash they're of equal precedence so evaluated strictly left to right an in C++ AND is higher.

Comment: really?????? downvote??? exactly for what? are you kidding?

Comment: omg!!! i give a good answer and this is what i get? guys really what is this ? :(

Comment: BTW, in Kleene's *Mathematical logic*, `∨` is stronger than `&` :-)

Comment: Also, in Javascript, `true | true | true && false` is `false` :-)

Comment: @StanislavKralin `|` and `||`, are different operators in javascript.  in JS, `true || true || true && false` is still `true` but, `true | true | true && false` is `false`

Comment: @Moher, I know it. Also, in JS, `|` is rather bitwise than logical... AFAIK, in C#, `|` is "polymorphic".

Comment: @StanislavKralin sorry just i thought you didn't notice the extra `|`... lol, and also I am familiar with them , but tnx anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to learn some few basic rules:

1. (a OR b) is true IF AND ONLY IF at least one of a or b is true.
2. (a AND b) is true IF AND ONLY IF both of a and b are true.
3. **ORDER of Operators MATTERS**: you can't just do the logic any way that you want. computer calculates the output of the a logical statement by an order. a simplified order is like this: First is **Grouping ()**, Second is **And**, Third is **OR**.

so when you say `bool c = true || true || true && false;`. the computer says ok let's first calculate `true && false`. it is false! and then it calculates `true || true || false` which is true.

**EDIT**

**Note 1**: a complete list of logical operators and their precedence is heavily dependent on the language. you can refer to the documentation for that.
[for C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx)

**Note 2**: the best practice is to use GROUPING like parenthesis because GROUPING is always of **priority**. for example it's better to say:
`bool c = (true || true) || (true && false);`

Answer (score 0):

Think of OR || like addition and AND && as multiplication. There is a priority in there, in fact, you will sometimes see them written as such:

```
bool c = true + true + true + true * false
```

In this case, the first evaluation is `true * false`, then the rest of the ORs. In this particular case, the true order of evaluation of the ORs will depend on language/compiler.

If you want to force a particular order, you can always use parentheses.